# Undefined Function in C

Tags: c

I have a prototype in my program declared in the last part of my program

here is the prototype:

```
int get_positive_int(void)
{
    int p;
    do {
        p = get_int("Positive integer: ");
    } while (p  < 0);
    return p;
}
```

I have declared it in the top (in the header files section)

```
int get_positive_int(void);
```

the error comes from this part:
(note: my program works if I remove this part)

```
    int o = get_postive_int();
    printf("%i\n", o);
```

it is not working, I have tried using different compilers.

Here is the full code:

it says: implicit declaration /
undefined reference to `get_int`

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototype

int get_positive_int(void);
int get_negative_int(void);

int main ()
{
    int i = get_negative_int();
    printf("%i\n", i);

    int o = get_postive_int();
    printf("%i\n", o);
}

// get negative integer from the user
int get_negative_int(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Negative interger: ");

    } while (n >= 0);
    return n;
}

int get_positive_int(void)
{
    int p;
    do {
        p = get_int("Positive integer: ");
    } while (p  < 0);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: "the error comes from this part" No, it doesn't. At least not the message you show. You show a function called `get_positive_int` while your error message mentions `get_int` which is not used in that line. Do you also have a prototype for `get_int` visible?

Comment: But there is also an error in the line you mentioned, but not the message you show. There is a typo in `get_positive_int` You wrote `get_postive_int`.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: And what is `get_int`? Where do you declare it? Where do you define (implement) it?

Comment: Is this a CS50 exercise?

Comment: If this is CS50, please add `#include <cs50.h>` to the top of your code and add the `cs50` tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the function `get_int` but it's nowhere either declared nor implemented so `gcc` doesn't know what to do with it.

As @Gerhardh also menttioned: You've got a little typo in line 11, you wrote `get_postive_int` instead of `get_positive_int`.

Anyhow, as it seems like that you just want to read an integer from stdin, you can use the [`scanf`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf) for this to read an integer from stdin. So in the end it could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum ReturnCode {
    Success,
    Error,
};

enum ReturnCode get_positive_int(int * num);
enum ReturnCode get_negative_int(int * num);

int main()
{
    enum ReturnCode status;

    int negative_num = 0;
    int positive_num = 0;

    status = get_negative_int(&negative_num);

    if (status == Error) {
        printf("A stdin error appeared. Aborting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Your negative integer: %i\n", negative_num);

    status = get_positive_int(&positive_num);
    if (status == Error) {
        printf("A stdin error appeared. Aborting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Your positive integer: %i\n", positive_num);

    return 0;
}

// get negative integer from the user
enum ReturnCode get_negative_int(int *num)
{
    for (;;) {
        printf("Negative Integer: ");
        if (scanf("%d", num) == 1 && *num < 0) {
            return Success;
        } else {
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
                if (c == EOF)
                    return Error;
            }
        }
    }
}

// get positive integer from the user
enum ReturnCode get_positive_int(int *num)
{
    for (;;) {
        printf("Positive Integer: ");
        if (scanf("%d", num) == 1 && *num >= 0) {
            return Success;
        } else {
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
                if (c == EOF)
                    return Error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yes, you're right

Comment: @chqrlie is it better now? Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I hope that this is fine now. Sorry for the circumstances, I see that I should write some C code again xD

Comment: sorry, my suggestion bypassed the do/while test. I updated the code with a simpler approach.